# Why tuple convention in function parameters?

Tags: python, coding-style, numpy

I was wondering why many functions - especially in numpy - utilize tuples as function parameters?

e.g.:

```
a = numpy.ones( (10, 5) )
```

What could possibly be the use for that? Why not simply have something such as the following, since clearly the first parameters will always denote the size of the array?

```
a = numpy.ones(10, 5)
```

Is it because there might be additional parameters, such as dtype? even if so,

```
a = numpy.ones(10, 5, dtype=numpy.int)
```

seems much cleaner to me, than using the convoluted tuple convention.

Thanks for your replies

Comment: Tuples make sense in cases where those numbers are going to be passed around together -- effectively, as a single value -- or where one can reasonably expect the caller to want to treat them that way.

Comment: Note that NumPy is not entirely consistent: [`ndarray.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) takes either a variable number of arguments *or* a tuple of them.

Comment: @larsmans - True, but for whatever it's worth, I'm fairly sure that was a relatively recent change (~`1.3`, maybe?). I definitely remember having to explicitly do `x.reshape((nrows, ncols))` instead of `x.reshape(nrows, ncols)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you want to be able to do:

```
a = numpy.ones(other_array.shape)
```

and `other_array.shape` is a tuple. There are a few functions that are not consistent with this and work as you've described, e.g. `numpy.random.rand()`

Comment: If `np.ones` took a variable number of arguments, `np.ones(*other.shape)` would have worked just fine, so this is not the whole story.

Comment: @mklauber: I'm sorry, I deleted my comment because I was getting the distinct impression I was confusing the issue because I don't know how the numpy function works.  I had originally said that the way `os.path.join` works bothers me, because I have to say `os.path.join(*args)` if I already have a list of pathnames to join.

It seems more appropriate to me to use a list or array as a function parameter than a variable number of parameters, because I am asking the function to work on one list of items that are the same kind of things.  It's also consistent with `str.join`.

Comment: np.ones(*other.shape) wouldn't work for functions that take multiple arguments.  Explicitly passing a single argument in allows that function to pass that same argument on to other functions.

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the benefits of this is that it can lead to consistency between the various methods.  I'm not that familiar with numpy, but it would seem to me the first use case that comes to mind is if numpy can return the size of an array, that size, as one variable, can be directly passed to another numpy method, without having to know anything about the internals of how that size item is built.

The other part of it is that size of an array may have two components but it's discussed as one value, not as two.

Answer (score 2):

My guess: this is because in functions like `np.ones`, `shape` can be passed as a keyword argument when it's a single value. Try

```
np.ones(dtype=int, shape=(2, 3))
```

and notice that you get the same value as you would have gotten from `np.ones((2, 3), dtype=int)`.

[This works in Python more generally:

```
>>> def f(a, b):
...     return a + b
... 
>>> f(b="foo", a="bar")
'barfoo'
```

]

Comment: This is the best answer, consistency can't be it - other functions _do_ use variable numbers of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In order for python to tell the difference between `foo(1, 2)`, `foo(1, dtype='int')` and `foo(1, 2, dtype='int')` you would have to use keyword-only arguments which weren't formally introduced until python 3. It is possible to use `**kargs` to implement keyword only arguments in python 2.x but it's unnatural and does not seem Pythonic. I think for that reason `array` does not allow `array(1, 2)` but `reshape(1, 2)` is ok because `reshape` does not take any keywords.